ROS noetic: weird sleep behavior of ros::Rate. I use ros::Rate(100) for a 100hz loop, but the frequent of loop is always 10Hz
My code is runing in Virtual Machine Ubuntu20.04. I use ros::Rate(100) for a 100hz loop, but the frequent of loop is always 10Hz. The code is like below:

The print is like below:

If I use the systme sleep library, the frequency could be raised up.

The publish rate is like below:

I am quite curious about this situtaion. Could anyone bring me a mind about it? Thanks.
